# graph algorithm for (economic) share graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory, economics

Hi to all graph theory experts :)

I'm currently facing an algorithmic problem which I cannot solve myself.

I have to find all indirect shares for each company to each other in a directed graph already containing the direct shares (see the image for a very simple example).

I have to start with a directed graph where the nodes are the companies and the edges the direct shares between these companies. The algorithm now has to append the indirect shares between all nodes to the edges (this includes adding new edges to the graph during the algorithm).

An indirect share is defined as the product of all intermediate direct shares. If there would be just nodes A, B and C in the graph, There would be only one indirect share, the one from A to C.

INDIRECT(A, C) = 100% * 80% = 1 * 0.8 = 0.8 = 80%

Now I need an algorithm that computes those shares for the whole graph. There is no specific starting point in the graph, and it may contain a variety of circles of each size (in the example there is only one "direct" circle between C and D) and multiple paths between a pair of nodes (like the paths from C to E).

It would be very helpful if anyone could help me out with some pseudo code or description of a possible algorithm. I already searched for algorithms in graph theory books and on the internet, but everything I can find is the standard algorithms for finding the shortest path, all paths, or visiting all nodes of a graph. But I cannot find a mechanism to calculate this kind of mathematical combination of the graph edge weights.

[example share graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7nZB.png)

Comment: My understanding is that C owns 50% of E directly and 25% of E via D for a total of 75%.

Comment: "The algorithm now has to append the indirect shares between all nodes to the edges" If you add the indirect shares to the edges representing direct shares, you will fall into problems.

Comment: I don't understand what's supposed to happen when there is a cycle -- how can two companies each partly own the other?

Comment: @j_random_hacker That's another one I thought about too. One possibility is to keep traversing the cycle. You can then keep adding the indirect share which will eventually converge to some number. Example: C has 50% of D directly. But since indirectly, C has also 50% * 20% * 50% of D which amounts to 5%. We can keep repeating the same process and add 0.5%, 0.05% and so on. To avoid an infinite loop we can stop when the number is no longer significant.

Comment: I think that what is to be done is now pretty clear and a recursive algorithm to generate all possible paths between each company and another, multiplying the shares along the edges and adding up the result of each distinct path. Partial results can be memoized for efficiency.

Comment: @Tarik: in my special case the edges are a data structure that can hold different values, e.g. the direct and indirect shares separately

Comment: @Tarik: this would be a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), right?

Comment: @Matthias The data structure does not matter as long as you conceptually have two distinct graphs. The fact that they share the same data structure might be practical but does not change the fact that they are different graphs.

Comment: @Matthias I did not do a complexity analysis but I would expect acceptable performance on a sparse graph. Moreover, memoization can cut down significantly on recalculations.

Comment: I just implemented a solution based on your proposal with traversing the circle over and over again until no significant change is made to the calculated values, which is just the definition of a geometrical progression. The geometric progression can be simplified by multiplying the original "simple" total share value (as it would be without the circles) with geoFactor = 1 / (1 - x), for example the total (direct + indirect) share between C and D would be 0.2 * geoFactor(C, D) = 0.2 * (1 / (1 - 0,5*0,2)) = 2,222. This also works fine for larger and separate cycles.

Comment: For a path from one node to another with larger cycles it would be simpleTotalShare * geoFactor(first, second) * geoFactor(second, third), ... 

And if the path "touches" multiple circles, the geoFactor consists of just all distinct pairs in all circles. In my first try I used all shares in all circles, but there are duplicates, which have to be removed first.

Answer (score 1):

Let us operationalise ownership by looking at what happens if a given company receives $1, and all money received is passed on to shareholders according to their ownership. We will then reckon the proportion of ownership to be the final proportion of money received when all the passing of money around has died down.

It is easiest to account first of all for the total money received by each company, and this will give us a set of linear equations whose solution will tell us the total amount of money received by every company when $1 is sent in the first instance to company A.

Suppose as an example that A and B own 1/2 of each other. Then a = 1 + b/2 and b = a/2, where a is the total amount of money received by A, and b is the total amount of money received by B - because A will get $1 and 1/2 of whatever B sees, and B will get 1/2 of what A sees. This solves as a = 1 + a/4 or a = 4/3 and b = 2/3. If we follow each step of the distribution then A receives 1 and sends 1/2 to B, who sends 1/4 to A, who sends 1/8 to B who sends 1/16 to A... so A gets 1 + 1/4 + 1/16 + ... = 4/3.

So A sees a total of 4/3 and B sees a total of 2/3 - but A and B have to pass on 1/2 of all they receive, so A ends up with 2/3 and B ends up with 1/3, which makes sense - the incoming $1 is exactly accounted for.

If we take the distribution of money as indicative of ownership, then A owns 2/3 of itself, and B owns the other 1/3.

Comment: The second method can be made more efficient by memoizing. Did you check how the first method will deal with cycles?

Comment: @Tarik - thanks for your comment. I have rewritten my answer, still using linear equations, to clarify what I am accounting for, and including an example with a very simple cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Find an algorithm which computes the length of the shortest path from the current node to all other nodes. Iterate this for each node. Store the results and use them to prevent having to repeat the same calculation for the same path.

Replace 'calculate the path' with 'calculate the indirect share' in the previous paragraph, and you've got yourself an algorithm.

Comment: I do not think we should use the shortest path. See my comment above.

Comment: This would only work if there were no circles in the graph

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't. What I meant say is that the part of the algorithm found in graph theory textbooks that handles finding the shortest path should be replaced by another heuristic unique to this problem. I was trying to quietly suggest to the OP to keep looking at typical graph problems and solutions and try to apply them to his own.